# Is it possible to loop particles on curve

Tags: animation, particles, loop

i was wondering. Is it possible to loop paticles moving on a curve path? And if it is, is there a way to loop them after they reach the end of the path so their movement on the curve can be saved in the animation.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - by "loop" do you mean repeat? Do you want the particles to move along a curve, then "jump" back to the beginning and do it again - OR - Do you want particles to move in a certain, repeating (looping) pattern, as they move along a curve?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Here is a link to the animation - https://drive.google.com/file/d/18pBXsBeHmo6pkVTr8YYZadBYP2VDBnL2/view?usp=sharing I want the particles on the 2 curves coming from the sides to be able to move on repeating loop pattern, so the animation can be used in a web site and not glich when repeating itself. I want to save the movement of them coming on the screen and then loop the second part of the video when they are fully shown on the screen

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with geometry nodes.

The points are placed randomly along the curve and an offset is added for each new frame. The offset should be 1/(total number of frame). The result modulus 1 will be a repeating pattern.

Here's a quick sketch up. Create a curve and add a geometry node like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/upYRS.png